# Maximum size of chains in Poset (P(S),R) where R is the relation Set containment

Tags: order-theory

Below is a question I was solving in an online exam for practice
[image]

And below they have given the solution.
My question is the relation $(P(S),\subseteq)$ is itself not a chain because say neither $\{1\}$ $\not\subseteq \{2\}$ nor $\{2\}$ $\not\subseteq \{1\}$.
So, how come they have given the size of the maximum chain to be 51?

Comment: It's not a chain **because** $\{1\}\not\subseteq\{2\}$ and $\{2\}\not\subseteq\{1\}$.

Comment: Yeah, that's is what I claim. And hence answer to this must be 0 right?

Comment: The answer to **what** is zero?

Comment: Answer to : "The maximum size of the chain in the poset $(P(S),\subseteq)$ "

Comment: A chain in the poset $(F, \subseteq)$ is a *subset* of $F$ which is totally ordered by $\subseteq$.  (I'm not sure myself what they mean by the part "that cover $F$" though.)

Comment: The answer is correct.  What followed is not a proof.

Comment: @William Elliot-Which answer?0 or 51?

Comment: @user3767495.  The given answer of 51.  What ensues is just an example of  maximal chain.  There are many more maximal chains.